# Add SystemSounds to PageView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want a sound to play with each page change in PageView. I have imported the services.dart package. There is an onPageChanged property in PageView but I can't figure out how to use it to make this happen. Or do I use GestureDetector? Or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Flutter does not support audio playing as of now (Feb 2019).

Use plugins like  this [pub.dartlang:audioplayers](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayers) to play audio.

It can be done by simply calling the function on an action that change the page or simply putting a trigger within the state.

Comment: I think you're right. There is a thread on gitHub https://github.com/rxlabz/audioplayer/issues/35  discussing the absence of notification sounds in Flutter.I can get a click with this:    onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details)
            {SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click
            );